# how can I make the choice of cities inside of specific region in Django admin?

Tags: django

I am a beginner in Django Frame work.

[image: Django admin]

when I click to the regions it should display all the available regions and after choosing specific region, inside that region it is available to choose a specific city

This is the code in models.py file:

```py
    
        from django.db import models
        
        class City(models.Model):
            city = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = 1)   
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.city
        
        class Region(models.Model):
            region = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            
            def __str__(self):
                return self.region
```

I was able to lad data without cities but with them I couldn't. json file:

```
    
        [
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Tashkent",
                    "city": [
                        "Angren",
                        "Bekobod",
                        "Bo'ka",
                        "Bo'stonliq",
                        "Chinoz",
                        "Chirchiq"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Namangan",
                    "city": [
                        "Chortoq",
                        "Chust",
                        "Kosonsoy",
                        "Mingbuloq",
                        "Namangan",
                        "Norin",
                        "Pop"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Andijon",
                    "city": [
                        "Andijon",
                        "Asaka",
                        "Baliqchi",
                        "Bo'z",
                        "Buloqboshi",
                        "Izboskan"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Fargona",
                    "city": [
                        "Beshariq",
                        "Bog'dod",
                        "Buvayda",
                        "Dang'ara",
                        "Farg'ona"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Navoiy",
                    "city": [
                        "Karman",
                        "Konimex",
                        "Navbahor",
                        "Navoiy",
                        "Nurota"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Surxandaryo",
                    "city": [
                        "Angor",
                        "Bandixon",
                        "Boysun",
                        "Denov",
                        "Jarqo'rgon"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Samarqand",
                    "city": [
                        "Bulung'ur",
                        "Ishtixon",
                        "Jomboy",
                        "Kattaqorg'on"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Buxara",
                    "city": [
                        "Buxoro",
                        "G'ijdivon",
                        "Jondor"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Jizzah",
                    "city": [
                        "Arnasoy",
                        "Baxmal",
                        "Do'stlik",
                        "Forish",
                        "Jizzax"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Xorazim",
                    "city": [
                        "Gurlan",
                        "Qo'shko'pir",
                        "Shovot",
                        "Urganch"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Sirdaryo",
                    "city": [
                        "Boyovut",
                        "Guliston",
                        "Oqoltin",
                        "Sardoba"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "models": "regions.region",
                "fields": {
                    "region": "Qashqadaryo",
                    "city": [
                        "Chiroqchi",
                        "Dehqonobod",
                        "G'uzor",
                        "Kasbi",
                        "Koson"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Please add some code to show what `Regions` is and what you're currently doing.

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots. Just copy & paste your actual code in here & format it using the code formatting of the editor (or ``` to open a code block and the same to close a code block)

Comment: Thank you for your help in posting @markwalker_ !!!